# Cross-compiling Boost: Can't find internal dependencies

Tags: linux, boost, cross-compiling

I'm on Windows and cross-compiling Boost to use on an embedded Linux device (it's a TS-7800 running some version of Debian). I've gotten Boost to compile correctly, but I'm running into an internal dependency problem. In particular, the Boost libraries can't find their own dependencies when I move them over to the TS-7800.

I'm calling the Boost compiler with the following:

```
b2 toolset=gcc-arm target-os=linux threadapi=pthread --build-dir=ts7800 --with-filesystem stage
```

(I'm using other libraries too but that's not as important.)

`b2` generates a ridiculous directory structure, so that the libraries end up in, e.g., `ts7800/boost/bin.v2/libs/system/build/gcc-arm/release/target-os-linux/threadapi-pthread/threading-multi/` under the Boost root directory.

The issue comes, though, when I try to use `filesystem`, which depends on `system`: When I call my executable that depends on `filesystem`, I get

```
./RegistryService: error while loading shared libraries:ts7800\boost\bin.v2\libs\system\build\gcc-arm\release\target-os-linux\threadapi-pthread\threading-multi\libboost_system-gcc-mt-1_53.so.1.53.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

When I call `readelf -d libboost_filesystem-gcc-mt-1_53.so`, I get

```
 Tag        Type          Name/Value
0x00000001  (NEEDED)     Shared library: [ts7800\boost\bin.v2\libs\system\build\gcc-arm\release\target-os-linux\threadapi-pthread\threading-multi\libboost_system-gcc-mt-1_53.so.1.53.0]
```

Is there some way to force Boost to not link that entire path into the library? Either by flattening the directory structure out or by changing them afterward?

Alternatively, is there a way to get Linux to recognize that directory path? I've tried copying that whole structure into both the directories of my executable and `libboost_filesystem-gcc-mt-1_53.so`, and adding the location of the directory to LD_LIBRARY_PATH, but none of these efforts seemed to work. (I'm a little skeptical of this route, though, because of the backslashes in the path.)

Thank you for your help!

Comment: 1) Boost libs should be in `ts7800/boost/stage/lib`. 2) Add --with-system to your b2 line.

Comment: 1) They get moved there, but they're still linked to the libraries deep in the directory, not the ones in /stage/lib
2) It's already compiling system, that's not the issue.

Comment: Ended up with just building boost on a Linux VM, and then it didn't mangle the directory structure.